# How to bind Display name of Dropdown value into Textbox field

Tags: infopath

Drop Down Filed name : DD

Text Field name      : Text

My infopath form drop down field (DD) value bind using "Enter Choice manually"

Drop down Values

```
Value   Display Name
1        One
2        Two
3        Three
4        Four
5        Five
```

On button click I set action "set field value"

In field i select Text , In value field i select DD

If i select option two in dropdown In Text field its value shown as "2" but i need Text field should be Two.

How to resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

Either change the value of drop down to "Two" in drop down settings OR create a rule before setting the TEXT field that converts the "2" to "Two".

Rule should be

CONDITION: If DD = 2

ACTION Set TEXT field to "Two"

Then create other rules for 1,3,4 and 5.